# Get divs id as array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers, closest

How to get the next div id number based on number (data-num = "7"), but only from divs that have attributes (data = "divdata"). Everything works normally but I can't get an array of these numbers. Where am I wrong in the code?

In this case the next number based on the number 7 should be 9, not 8(because it does not contain attributes data="divdata")

```
<div class="number" data-num="7"></div>

<div class="divclass" id="1" data="divdata"></div>
<div class="divclass" id="2"></div>
<div class="divclass" id="4" data="divdata"></div>
<div class="divclass" id="5" data="divdata"></div>
<div class="divclass" id="8"></div>
<div class="divclass" id="9" data="divdata"></div>
<div class="divclass" id="12" data="divdata"></div>
```

```
     var els = document.getElementsByClassName("divclass");
     for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++){
     var num_min = document.querySelectorAll('.divclass[data=divdata]')[i].id;
     
     var num_min_array = num_min;
     
     var number = document.getElementsByClassName("number")[0].getAttribute("data-num");

     const array1 = [num_min_array];
     var next_num = array1.find(element => element > number);
     alert(next_num);
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cache your number and elements before the loop, you can simply loop over the elements that have divdata and match their ids to the number, breaking the loop once the next number's been found.

```js
// Grab the number from the data attribute
const number = document.querySelector('.number').dataset.num;

// Grab all the datadiv elements
const divdatas = document.querySelectorAll('[data="divdata"]');

for (let i = 0; i < divdatas.length; i++) {

  // Coerce the strings to numbers
  const id = +divdatas[i].id;
  const last = +divdatas[divdatas.length - 1].id;
  const num = +number;

  // If the last id in the array matches the number
  // only log the second to last number
  if (last === num) {
    console.log(divdatas[divdatas.length - 2].id);
    break;
  }

  if (id > number) {
    console.log(divdatas[i - 1].id, divdatas[i].id);
    break;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="number" data-num="7"></div>

<div class="divclass" id="1" data="divdata"></div>
<div class="divclass" id="2"></div>
<div class="divclass" id="4" data="divdata"></div>
<div class="divclass" id="5" data="divdata"></div>
<div class="divclass" id="8"></div>
<div class="divclass" id="9" data="divdata"></div>
<div class="divclass" id="12" data="divdata"></div>
```

Comment: This seems to work. What needs to be changed in the code to get also the next smallest number before 7 (that would be 5)?

Comment: You log the number at the previous index. Answer updated.

Comment: I had to change to `divdatas[i - 2].id` , now works normally, I do not know why. Why when I type the maximum number `<div class = "number" data-num = "12"> </div>` I don't get any result (undefined), I should get the number 9?

Comment: Your original question was about the next higher number; there is no higher number than 12 which is why the code doesn't work.

Comment: Andy that is true, but if I go to the next smaller number [i - 1]. If I put data-num = "7" the next smaller number is 5 and that's fine. Everything works unless I put the highest number. With 12 the next smaller number should be 9 but I don't get anything.

Comment: This works. I will put it as the correct answer. The only drawback is if number has a number that contains data = "divdata", then it does not work. For example, if the number is data-num = "4", it does not work because id4 has data = "divdata". I do not mind...

Answer (score 0):

can you use jquery? It would be much easier
$('[data=divdata]') and you will get an array with all elements that has this attribute

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.divclass[data=divdata]')` is the same thing.

Comment: How get array in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Use the ***nextSibling*** and ***previousSibling*** properties:

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
```

```
document.getElementById('2').nextSibling; // returns 3
document.getElementById('2').previousSibling; // returns 1
```

Comment: The next value after `1` should be `3` according to OP because only `data="divdata"` should count.

Comment: Is it possible to use nextSibling, in the example described above. To be used together with data = "divdata"?

Answer (score 0):

map and filter approach.

```
var number = document.getElementsByClassName("number")[0].getAttribute("data-num");
var itemsWithDivData = document.querySelectorAll('.divclass[data=divdata]');
var arrayOfDivDataIds = [...itemsWithDivData].map(item => parseInt(item.id)).filter(item => item > parseInt(number));
var nextItemId = arrayOfDivDataIds.sort(function(a, b){return a-b})[0];

console.log(nextItemId);
```

Comment: Just a note: `[...itemsWithDivData].map(item => parseInt(item.id))` can also be `Array.from(itemsWithDivData, item => parseInt(item.id))` to do the conversion into array + mapping at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the next div id with the attribute of (data = "divdata")

so, you can use:

```
var next_num; 
  array1.find(ele =>{
    if(ele > number) {
      next_num = ele;   
    }
  })
```

instead of

```
var next_num = array1.find(element => element > number);
```

then you get your desired div id.

Comment: then i get ..., num_min (Cannot read property 'id' of undefined)

Comment: This error occurs because you use 'id' attribute in your code,

`var num_min = document.querySelectorAll('.divclass[data=divdata]')[i].id;`

because of this below mention code

`var els = document.getElementsByClassName("divclass");`

you get all the divs that have ('divclass') but some of them do not have an attribute of ('data=divdata') because of this you get undefined and undefined does not have an 'id' attribute.

Comment: Ok, but now i get all numbers after 7, i need get only one number 9, not 9 and 12...

Comment: Now you can execute this code it will give your desired output.
```var els = document.querySelectorAll('.divclass');
for(var i=0; i<els.length; i++){
var get_desired_div=document.getElementsByClassName("divclass")[i].hasAttribute('data');
if(get_desired_div){var num_min=document.getElementsByClassName("divclass")[i].id}
var num_min_array = num_min;
var number = document.getElementsByClassName("number")[0].getAttribute("data-num");
const array1 = [num_min_array];
var next_num; 
array1.find(ele =>{ if(ele > number) { next_num = ele;}})
console.log(next_num);}```